# discord.py создание канала с правами для двух игроков

Tags: python, discord.py

Делаю что-то типа стратегии в дискорде через бота, основанного на библиотеке discord.py. И возникает проблема с созданием прав для канала переговоров. Следующий код просто создает канал, но его никто не может видеть(кроме администрации). Как бы это можно было решить?

```
@bot.command()
async def дипломатия(ctx, type: str, country: discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(1015934332860370965)
    author_id=ctx.author.id
    if type == 'переговоры':
        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Дипломатия")
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{author_id}-{country}', category=category)
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
        await channel.set_permissions(author_id, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        await channel.set_permissions(country, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

сообщество! Ответ на вопрос найден мною же и вот мой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def дипломатия(ctx, type: str, country: discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(1015934332860370965)
    author_id=ctx.author
    if type == 'переговоры':
        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Дипломатия")
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{author_id}-{country}', category=category)
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
        await channel.set_permissions(author_id, speak=True, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        await channel.set_permissions(country, speak=True, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
```

Я надеюсь, что кому-нибудь это понадобится. В общем, ошибка заключалась в **author_id=ctx.author.id**. Айди добывать не нужно